# Linear-logarithmic Regression in MATLAB with two input arguments - which model to assume?

Tags: regression, matlab, curve-fitting, logarithm

Look at the following plot and ignore the solid lines please (just look at the dotted/dashed ones).

[image]

ONE curve is described by the following parameters and ONE fixed value for the second input parameter V:

- X-axis: Input-Parameter `T`
- Y-axis: Output-Parameter `g`

For each curve, `g` is between [0, 255] (thus always positive), concave, bijective.
I know from the process that lies behind the measures, that by increasing `V`, the corresponding curve flattens.

The different curves result when varying `V`. The orange curve at the top is for like `V=100`, the bottom curve (red/magenta) results for `V=180`.

I have measured data with a lot more data points in the following form:

```
T[1]  V[1]  g[1]
T[2]  V[1]  g[2]
T[3]  V[1]  g[3]
...   V[1]  g[4]
T[N]  V[1]  g[5]
.......
T[1]  V[N]  g[1]
T[2]  V[N]  g[2]
T[3]  V[N]  g[3]
...   V[N]  g[4]
T[N]  V[N]  g[5]
```

Now I want a regression like this:

```
g = g(V, T)
```

which would yield the curve for a fixed V-value:

```
g = g(T), V=Vfix
```

Which regression-funktion in MATLAB do you think would work out the best way?
And how to assume a "model" here?
I only know (from the process itself AND obviously from the plots), that its some sort of linear curve at the beginning, pass over into a logarithmic curve, but I dont know how the value of `V` inferfers with it!?

Thanks a lot in advance: for any advice..